# Rails nested form adds before parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is Dog model and Specie model, which belongs to Dog. When create Dog, Rails also generate nested form to add specie, through button 'add specie'. The trouble is that in view after adding nested form takes place before parent form. If I add a lot additional nested forms, parent form is the last form. For sure not good.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :species_attributes
  has_many :species
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :species
  validates :name, :presence => true
end

class Specie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :specie_id
  belongs_to :dog
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

<

```
div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :species do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'specie_fields', :f=> builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to_add_fields 'Add Specie', f, :species %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

_specie_fields.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name, 'Specie' %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<%= button_to_function 'Specie delete', 'remove_fields(this)' %>
</div>
```

helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def button_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    button_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
end
```

JS file:

```
 function add_fields(link, association, content) {
        var new_id = new Date().getTime();
        var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
        $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS file replace `parent().before` with just `before` as shown below:

```
 $(link).before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
```

This way you insert your partial before the button (`$(link)` is `this` from this line in your helper: `button_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, ...`), and not before it's parent (which is whatever is the parent of your `<%= button_to_add_fields 'Add Specie', f, :species %>`, probably the entire form).

Comment: that was close... but now it adds below of all page, after the buttons

Comment: drop .parent(). do just `$(link).before(...)`

Comment: thanks! that works. May be you can add a answer separately, so I can vote for that. Can you explain why dripping parent() works?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your JS function "add_fields".

This function add your nested form in the wrong place.

Comment: added JS file. May be you can find mistake